# Array of structs not adding

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Hey so we started using C in University a month ago and now we've got an assignment and we need to use dynamic allocation on an array of structs. This is my code for creating the repo:
'''

```
Repo* init() {
    Repo* repo = malloc(sizeof(Repo));
    repo->items = malloc(sizeof(Item) * 1);
    repo->allocatedSlots = 1;
    repo->numberOfItems = 0;
    return repo;
}

typedef struct {
    Item *items;
    int numberOfItems;// the index of the last item
    int allocatedSlots;
}Repo;
```

'''
And these are the functions I am testing and I get the assertion failed:
'''

```
int grow(Repo* repo) {
    assert(repo != NULL);
    assert(repo->items != NULL);
    Item* new_repo = malloc((2 * repo->allocatedSlots)*sizeof(Item));
    if (new_repo == NULL)
        return 0; //allocation fail!
    memcpy(new_repo, repo->items, sizeof(Repo) * repo->numberOfItems);
    free(repo->items);
    repo->items = new_repo;
    repo->allocatedSlots *= 2;
    free(new_repo);
    return 1; //success
}

int addItem(Repo* repo, Item item) {
    for (int index = 0; index < repo->numberOfItems; index++)
        if (repo->items[index].ID == item.ID)
            return 0;// item already exists
    //printf("%d %d", item.ID, item.value);
    if (repo->numberOfItems < repo->allocatedSlots) {
        char* type = (char*)malloc(strlen(item.type)*sizeof(char)), *state = (char*)malloc(strlen(item.state) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(type, item.type);
        strcpy(state, item.state);
        //repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1] = &item;
        repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1].ID = (int)item.ID;
        //printf("JSJSJSJS  %d", repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1].ID);
        repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1].value = item.value;
        strcpy(repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1].state, state);
        strcpy(repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1].type, type);
        repo->numberOfItems++;
    }
    else {
        grow(repo);
        repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1].ID = item.ID;
        repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1].value = item.value;
        strcpy(repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1].state, item.state);
        strcpy(repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1].type, item.type);
        repo->numberOfItems++;
    }
    return 1;//adding successfull!
}

void AddItem_ValidInput_AddedToList() {
    Repo* repo = init();

    Item item ;
    int id = 1, value = 100;
    char* state = "New";
    char* type = "Uglyo";
    item = createItem(id, value, state, type);
    addItem(repo, item);
    //printf("sdfsdfsdfs");
    //printf('%d\n', repo->items[0].ID);
    assert(repo->items[0].ID == item.ID);
    //printf('%d', item->ID);
    destroy(repo);

}
```

'''
The last one is the test case I am doing first.

Comment: Where are the variables? How are you calling it? Cannot be answered with the provided information, but an assertion failure is normally trivial to find and fix - especially yours which are just null checks. Obviously something is null. Did you forget to call init() ?

Comment: And how about the `assert`? Which one is firing? Please consider what info the readers would need.

Comment: The one I added last. Where I check if the item on position [0] is the same as the one created through the Domain.

Comment: Your indices are off in `addItem`. For example, `repo->items[repo->numberOfItems + 1].ID` the index should be `repo->numberOfItems`. Same for all the others after that line. Just consider your `assert(repo->items[0].ID == item.ID);`. It's looking at index `0` but the `+1` in `addItem` ensures index 0 is never filled in.

Comment: Why not use [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) instead of manually calling `malloc` and `memcpy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely here:

```
char* type = (char*)malloc(strlen(item.type)*sizeof(char)), *state = (char*)malloc(strlen(item.state) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(type, item.type);
strcpy(state, item.state);
```

Here you forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings. A *string* in C is a sequence of characters, terminated by a zero. This zero is *not* counted by `strlen`, but it still needs space allocated for it.

You need to allocate `strlen(...) + 1` bytes for the strings:

```
char* type = malloc(strlen(item.type) + 1);
char* state = malloc(strlen(item.state) + 1);
strcpy(type, item.type);
strcpy(state, item.state);
```

Or if your system have the `strdup` function (very likely)

```
char* type = strdup(item.type);
char* state = strdup(item.state);
```

---

You also have very serious problems with your `grow` function:

```
Item* new_repo = malloc((2 * repo->allocatedSlots)*sizeof(Item));
repo->items = new_repo;
free(new_repo);
```

First you allocate memory and make `new_repo` point to that memory.

Then you make `repo->items` point to *the same memory*. You now have two pointers pointing to the exact same memory.

Then you free that memory, making both the `new_repo` *and* the `repo->items` pointers invalid.

You should not `free(new_repo)`.

Or use e.g. [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) instead (as already suggested by me in a comment):

```
int grow(Repo* repo) {
    Item* new_repo = realloc(repo->items, 2 * repo->allocatedSlots * sizeof(Item));
    if (new_repo == NULL)
        return 0;  // Failure to allocate

    repo->items = new_repo;
    repo->allocatedSlots *= 2;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: True and OP should fix that. But looks like the test case will not trigger `grow`.

Comment: Allright but when I use this method, I get access violation as soon as I try to call the function.